# Changing cursor from wait to default does not work while changing form

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

We have an Windows Mobile 6 project that have been up and running for two years.

While developing a new version the cursor changes have stop work on some of our devices.

The most problematic place is when change forms. The code is basically:

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;            
ShowForm(FormSettings);
FormSettings.ReInit();
Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
```

The WaitCursor appears but never disappears.

When debugging I can clearly see that all lines of code are executed and after the last statement I can check the value of Cursor.Current in the "watch" or "Immediate" window and see that it clearly is set to Cursors.Default (or rather the value of Cursor.Default - something with "ARROW").

More information:

If I in the end of the `FormSettings.ReInit()` add a `MessageBox.Show("")` the cursor will dissapear/become Cursors.Default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to handle all the cursor changes in the code of the forms.

Not sure why half of it worked even in the other approach but now it all works.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen when there is an unhandled exception in one of your routines.

If an exception is not being thrown, then it is occurring either in a threaded routine, a LINQ query, or a form's `InitializeComponent()` section.

To get your `Cursor` back, do the following:

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
try {
  ShowForm(FormSettings);
  FormSettings.ReInit();
} finally {
  Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
}
```

But, you have a problem somewhere in `ShowForm` or `ReInit()`. You should go to those routines and add a `try...catch` in there until you get it sorted out.

Comment: Thanks, should have added that I could step through the code and had verified that all lines are executed and the value of Cursor.Current is set correctly. Updated the question accordingly.